# Prevent break routing issue on error in Angular 2

Tags: angular, routes

As I notice that when any error occurs in `Angular 2` app, It breaks routing also. Is there any way to handle this and prevent break routing issue?

Comment: As JavaScript is asynchronous language, it doesn't execute further code after any error. It is all about developer's coding practice, how they handle exceptions and make the application break free.

Please let us know if you have some specific scenario.

Answer (score 2):

No, almost any not handled error will break Angular app, not only router. You must handle/catch/prevent all errors.